# Objective-c: Singleton - passing variables

Tags: objective-c, singleton

I have a singleton that I'd like to use to manage the onscreen animation of my views. Here's my.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface OAI_AnimationManager : NSObject {

    NSMutableDictionary* sectionData;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary* sectionData;

+(OAI_AnimationManager* )sharedAnimationManager;

- (void) checkToggleStatus : (UIView* ) thisSection;

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "OAI_AnimationManager.h"

@implementation OAI_AnimationManager

@synthesize sectionData;

+(OAI_AnimationManager *)sharedAnimationManager {

static OAI_AnimationManager* sharedAnimationManager;

@synchronized(self) {

    if (!sharedAnimationManager)

        sharedAnimationManager = [[OAI_AnimationManager alloc] init];

    return sharedAnimationManager;

}

}

- (void) checkToggleStatus : (UIView* ) thisSection {

    //get the section data dictionary
     NSLog(@"%@", sectionData);

}



@end
```

You'll see in the .h file I added a NSMutableDictionary and am using @property/@synthesize for it's getter and setter.

In my ViewController I instantiate the animation manager as well as a series of subclasses of UIView called Section. With each one I store the data (x/y w/h, title, etc.) in a dictionary and pass that to the dictionary delcared in animation manager. In the Section class I also instantiate animation manager and add a UITapGestureRecognizer which calls a method, which passes along which section was tapped to a method (checkToggleStatus) in animation manager.

As you can I see in the method I am just logging sectionData. Problem is I am getting null for the value.

Maybe my understanding of singletons is wrong. My assumption was the class would only be instantiated once, if it was already instantiated then that existing object would be returned.

I do need all the other Section classes data as if one animates others animate in response and I can get around it by passing the tapped Section to the animation manager and doing [[Section superview] subviews] and then looping and getting the data from each that way but it seems redundant since that data is available in the ViewController when they are created.

Am I doing something wrong in trying to transfer that data? Is there a better solution? I am open to suggestions and criticisms.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

h file

```
@interface OAI_AnimationManager : NSObject 

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary* sectionData;

+(OAI_AnimationManager* )sharedAnimationManager;

- (void) checkToggleStatus : (UIView* ) thisSection;

@end
```

m file

```
static OAI_AnimationManager* _sharedAnimationManager;

@implementation OAI_AnimationManager

@synthesize sectionData = _sectionData;

+(OAI_AnimationManager *)sharedAnimationManager {


    @synchronized(self) {

        if (!_sharedAnimationManager) {

            _sharedAnimationManager = [[OAI_AnimationManager alloc] init];
        }
    }

    return _sharedAnimationManager;

}


- (void) checkToggleStatus : (UIView* ) thisSection {

     //get the section data dictionary

     NSLog(@"%@", _sectionData);

}
```

@end

Notice I moved your sectionData variable from the header and moved it to the implementation file.  A while back, they changed it to where you can synthesize properties and specify their instance variable names along side it... hence:

sectionData = _sectionData;

I also added and underscore to the instance variable... this is a universal convention for private variables and it also will throw a compile error now if you try to type just **sectionData** as you did in the return statement of checkToggleStatus:.  Now you either have to type **self.sectionData** or **_sectionData**.

You didn't include the code that creates an instance of your dictionary but I bet you didn't set it as **self.sectionData = [[NSDictionary alloc] init]** which means it would not retain the value and you would get null the next time you called it.  Classic memory management mistake... I know it well because I learned the hard way hehehe

Comment: Weird that you provide an example of dropping and this morning I was just reading this blog post...http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/, which talks of the same thing. Let me try out your suggestion and see if I have any success...